# AWS Amplify GraphQL API in Vue App Returns Null

Tags: vuejs2, graphql-js, aws-appsync, aws-amplify, aws-mobilehub

I am using AWS-Amplify for generating GraphQL back-end in a simple Vue2 Task Management application for practice.

I have configured my application correctly to use amplify-vue components. All looks fine as there are no errors. I have generated correct schema using AppSync console, and have created mutations and queries for CRUD demo as shown below.

**Schema**

```
type Mutation {
    createTask(input: TaskInput): Task
    updateTask(id: ID!, input: TaskInput): Task
    deleteTask(id: ID!): Task
}

type Query {
    fetchTask(id: ID): Task
}

type Task {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    completed: Boolean!
}

input TaskInput {
    name: String!
    completed: Boolean!
}
```

**Query**

```
query listTasks {
  listTasks {
    items {
      id
      name
      completed
    }
  }
}
```

**Mutations**

```
mutation addTask($name: String!, $completed: Boolean!) {
  createTask(
    input: {
      name: $name,
      completed: $completed
    }
  ) {
    name
    completed
  }
}


mutation updateTask($id: ID!, $name: String!, $completed: Boolean!) {
  updateTask(
    input: {
      id: $id
      name: $name
      completed: $completed
    }
  ) {
    id
    name
    completed
  }
}

mutation deleteTask($id: ID!) {
  deleteTask(
    input: {
      id: $id
    }
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

To start off with my application, I create new task but get error in console:

> Variable 'name' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'String!'

Then I check in AppSync Console by running the following `createTask` mutation:

```
mutation {
    createTask(
    input: {
      name: "Waleed",
      completed: false
    }
  ) {
    name
    completed
  }
}
```

And this time the following response gets returned:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createTask": null
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me out what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please share the request & response mapping templates for your Mutation.createTask resolver?

Comment: Finally made it working!!! I feel silly for not adding revolvers! But I guess that's all fine because this is what learning by doing is all about especially when one like me is starting as novice :p

Comment: Glad you got it working! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @mparis: Thank you. Regarding subscriptions, I am trying to subscribe to changes on delete, create and update mutations. In amplify-vue official guide, there is only mentioning of adding :subscription="onCreateTask" with :query directive in template. I wonder how can I add other (update and delete subscriptions) in same component template so that on any of mentioned mutations, I get new list of tasks (for example).

Comment: In your schema, you can control what mutations subscription fields subscribe to using the @aws_subscribe directive. For example, you can create a subscription field that listens to all those mutations with `type Subscription { onAll: Task @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createTask","updateTask","deleteTask"]) }`

Comment: Super awesome! I did what you outlined above and made it kind of working. That is I set ```:subscription="onAllMutations"``` which covers all mutations in schema. But in case of getting back a response ```:onSubscriptionMsg=SomeFunction``` I am receiving old list of tasks from ```response.data.listOfTasks``` So how should I know which mutation was provoked and thus update the ```data.listOfTasks``` ?